# Adding more types to template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have a simple templated class which I instantiate for each type that uses it like so:

```
template<class T> struct meta {
  static const std::string& get_name() {return T::class_name;}
};

template<> struct meta<double> {
  static constexpr const char* class_name = "double";
  static const char* get_name() { return class_name; }
};

template<> struct meta<std::vector<double> {
  static constexpr const char* class_name = "std::vector<double>";
  static const char* get_name() { return class_name; }
};

template<> struct meta<std::array<double,2>> {
  static constexpr const char* class_name = "double[]";
  static const char* get_name() { return class_name; }
};
```

Then I can use these like so:

```
int main() {
  std::cout << meta<double>::get_name() << '\n';
  std::cout << meta<std::vector<double> >::get_name() << '\n';
  std::cout << meta<std::array<double,2> >::get_name() << '\n';
}
```

I use macros to generate variants of the template-specialization for each base-type, but I'm stuck on `std::array` because it contains a base-type *and* an integer.  I'd like to find out how to add a new templated parameter to an already-templated specialization so that I don't need to specialize for each possible value of integer.

I've tried:

```
template<int I> struct meta<std::array<double,I>> {
    static constexpr const char* class_name = "double[]";
    static const char* get_name() { return class_name; }
};
```

> error: ‘class_name’ is not a member of ‘std::array’

Comment: To have partial template specification, you need full template specification first.

Comment: not sure how to fix it, but the issue is: your meta expects a class type as parameter, but `array` is a template.

Comment: ... you already have a full template specification. Let me try the code.

Comment: Change `int` to `size_t`.

Comment: Wow, that works.  Thanks!  I'm glad it was so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `std::array` C++ [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
template< 
    class T, 
    std::size_t N 
> struct array;
```

So, you need

```
template<std::size_t I> struct meta<std::array<double, I>> {
    static constexpr const char* class_name = "double[]";
    static const char* get_name() { return class_name; }
};
```

Because `int` and `std::size_t` are two different types (having different signed-ness), the partial template specialization won't match. Changing `int` to `size_t` works.

---

In summary: Read the documentation.

Comment: I was guessing at the full template specification syntax.  I'm glad my intuition was close and that the error was so simple.